# array retain in table view objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a small confusion. When I print my array in tableView dataSource method numberOfRowsInSection , my App crashes.

This is my code : in .h file

```
@interface AddColor : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
UITableView *tblView;
NSArray *arrayColors;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *arrayColors;

@end
```

In .m file

```
@synthesize arrayColors;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

     arrayColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"blackColor", @"darkGrayColor", @"lightGrayColor", @"whiteColor",  @"grayColor", @"redColor", @"greenColor", @"blueColor", @"cyanColor", @"yellowColor", @"magentaColor", @"orangeColor", @"purpleColor", @"brownColor", nil];


    tblView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tblView.delegate=self;
    tblView.dataSource=self;
    [self.view addSubview:tblView];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

   NSLog(@"%d",[arrayColors count]);//App crashes here.
   return [arrayColors count];
}
```

My app crashes when I print [arrayColors count];

I find the solution for crash, I simply retain the array  in viewDidLoad

```
[arrayColor retain];
```

and now working fine. but why my app crashes before when I print the [arrayColor count];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+ [NSArray arrayWithObjects:]
```

creates an autoreleased array - it's unsepcified when it is released, but most likely it's released when the `viewDidLoad` method returns, so it's an invalid (garbage) pointer that you access in `[arrayColor count]`.

By retaining the array, you get rid of the deallocation error, but now you're leaking memory. The general approach of solving this the right way is to allocate and initialize the array in one of the initializer methods, like

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        arrayColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:..., nil];
    }
    return self;
```

}

and then purge it in `- dealloc` in order not to leak memory:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [arrayColors release];
    [super dealloc];
```

}

More on the topic on [Apple Developer.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using [self.arrayColors count] - use the ivar getters and setters to access the retained property
2. As an aside, I would strongly advise against hardcoding the size of your tableview.  At the very least set the autoresizing mask.

Answer (score 0):

You might've linked the DataSource and Delegate to your TableView instead of the File Owner.

Answer (score 0):

if you do this,

```
 [self setArrayColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"blackColor", @"darkGrayColor", @"lightGrayColor", @"whiteColor",  @"grayColor", @"redColor", @"greenColor", @"blueColor", @"cyanColor", @"yellowColor", @"magentaColor", @"orangeColor", @"purpleColor", @"brownColor", nil]];
```

it should fix the problem without requiring another retain, but make sure you release it in the dealloc.

```
  [arrayColors release];
```